# Please fix my program error i m stuck

Tags: oop

i am using visual C++ 2010 i m having just one error i want user to enter inputs model and color and then it will pass to a public variable and public member function will access private data members and assign values to it then a public member function will display those values main.when i try to write s1.colr[10] to pass it to fuunction it gives error.

## include

```
using namespace std;
#include<conio.h>
class vehicle
{
private:
int d;
char color[10];
public:
int mdl;
char colr[10];
    void get_input(int a,char b[10])
    {
        
        d=a ;
        color[10]=b[10];
    }
void disp()
{
    cout<<"Model Number Is:"<<d ;
    cout<<"Color Is:"<<color[10];
}   
};
int main()
{
vehicle s1;
cout<<"Enter Model Number:";
cin>>s1.mdl;
cout<<"Enter Color:";
    cin>>s1.colr[10];
    s1.get_input(s1.mdl,s1.colr[10]);
s1.disp();
getch();
    
}
```

Comment: *What* error? Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `s1.colr` insterad of `so.colr[10]`

```
cin>>s1.colr[10];
s1.get_input(s1.mdl,s1.colr[10]);
```

and you code will compile.

Don't use `conio.h`, `#inlude <iostream>`.

**<kbd>[Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fcd5564ff8dcfe6)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thomas but if i do so it will store only first alphabet not the whole color name like "red" it will display "r" only

Comment: if i dont use conio then i cannot use getch(); when using return 0; program runs but when i put values and press enter rather than showing values it closes off ...

Comment: No, it will store the whole name. I've added a slightly improved variant of your code.